# Setting dateRangeInput min/max based on data

Tags: r, shiny

My question is related to [Using dynamic dates in Shiny dateRangeInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271849/using-dynamic-dates-in-shiny-daterangeinput), however I'm still unsure how to resolve the issue. I have code as shown below:

```
data <- read.csv('data.csv')
#data has a column named 'date' which has a min value of 2002-01-01 and a max of 2016-03-01.   

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(inputId='daterange', label='Select Model Build Period', 
    min = min(data$date), max = max(data$date)
  )
)
```

However, this doesn't work and it seems like it's not possible to set the `min` and `max` for `dateRangeInput` in `ui` based on a data frame or vector. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check to see how the data was stored when you read it in: `class(data$date)`. My guess is that you will have to read it in using the `as.is=TRUE` argument, then convert it to date manually using `as.Date()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using data to dynamically define the date range, you'll want to render the `dateRangeInput` in the `server.R`, using [`renderUI`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)

So in **server.R** you'll have

```
data <- read.csv('data.csv')

output$daterange <- renderUI({

    dateRangeInput(inputId='daterange', 
                   label='Select Model Build Period', 
                   min = min(data$date), 
                   max = max(data$date)
                  )

})
```

and in **ui.R** you'll have

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    ....
    uiOutput("daterange")
    ....
)
```

Comment: How can I then select `daterange` for use later?

Comment: I figured it out. I can just use `input$daterange`.